# How to use translation in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm working with angular translate, and in my language file I have this :

```
"END_MESSAGE" : "Dilato avunculus fiduciam astute genere navata  {{date}}. tuto diligens ut praepotens quo turbulentos eum est in."
```

I want to format `{{date}}` to the current year, so in my html I have this :

```
   <p>{{ 'FME_CANDIDATURE.AFTER_CANDIDATURE.END_MESSAGE' | translate : '{date : currentYear}'}}</p>
```

and in my controller I've this :

```
$scope.currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
```

but I'm getting that message without the date.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Can you pls share the filter??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing
    `<p>{{ 'FME_CANDIDATURE.AFTER_CANDIDATURE.END_MESSAGE' | translate : '{date : currentYear}'}}</p>`

with 
    `<p translate="FME_CANDIDATURE.AFTER_CANDIDATURE.END_MESSAGE" translate-values='{ date: currentYear}'></p>`
solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full year from your date object like this.

```
{{dateObject | date: 'yyyy'}}
```

Let me know if this helps.